# unable to build iOS project using Github actions

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I have a simple iOS project (just a new project created with Xcode) that I can build and test locally.

I want to integrate Github actions for CI/CD.

Here is my workflow script:

```
name: iOS starter workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Test default scheme using any available iPhone simulator
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set Default Scheme
        run: |
          scheme_list=$(xcodebuild -list -json | tr -d "\n")
          default=$(echo $scheme_list | ruby -e "require 'json'; puts JSON.parse(STDIN.gets)['project']['targets'][0]")
          echo $default | cat >default
          echo Using default scheme: $default
      - name: Build
        env:
          scheme: ${{ 'default' }}
          platform: ${{ 'iOS Simulator' }}
        run: |
          # xcrun xctrace returns via stderr, not the expected stdout (see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663959)
          device=`xcrun xctrace list devices 2>&1 | grep -oE 'iPhone.*?[^\(]+' | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | sed -e "s/ Simulator$//"`
          if [ $scheme = default ]; then scheme=$(cat default); fi
          if [ "`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`" ]; then filetype_parameter="workspace" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`"; else filetype_parameter="project" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcodeproj\$`"; fi
          file_to_build=`echo $file_to_build | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`
          xcodebuild build-for-testing -scheme "$scheme" -"$filetype_parameter" "$file_to_build" -destination "platform=$platform,name=$device"
      - name: Test
        env:
          scheme: ${{ 'default' }}
          platform: ${{ 'iOS Simulator' }}
        run: |
          # xcrun xctrace returns via stderr, not the expected stdout (see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663959)
          device=`xcrun xctrace list devices 2>&1 | grep -oE 'iPhone.*?[^\(]+' | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | sed -e "s/ Simulator$//"`
          if [ $scheme = default ]; then scheme=$(cat default); fi
          if [ "`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`" ]; then filetype_parameter="workspace" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcworkspace\$`"; else filetype_parameter="project" && file_to_build="`ls -A | grep -i \\.xcodeproj\$`"; fi
          file_to_build=`echo $file_to_build | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`
          xcodebuild test-without-building -scheme "$scheme" -"$filetype_parameter" "$file_to_build" -destination "platform=$platform,name=$device"
```

The problem is that the action fails at the build step and complains about the destination.

here is the output:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
        { platform:iOS Simulator, OS:latest, name:'iPhone 11' }
    The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.
    Ineligible destinations for the "HelloActions" scheme:
        { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
        { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
Error: Process completed with exit code 70.
```

I tried to change the destination, but no matter what device I try to use, it gives the exact same error every time.

I can run the exact same command on my local machine and it builds the project without any issue.

I even tried getting a list of available devices with `xcrun xctrace list devices` and using one of them, but it still says the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of trying everything, I found the real issue and the solution.

I tried running unit tests using `fastlane`. after pushing to the repo, I found out that the actual problem was about the deployment target. The deployment target for my project was `iOS 15.4` but the latest version that the Github actions supports is `15.2`. that's why I couldn't build my project.

Then I changed the script and included the OS version for destination and Voila.
Here's the updated line in the script:

```
xcodebuild build-for-testing -scheme "$scheme" -"$filetype_parameter" "$file_to_build" -destination "platform=$platform,OS=15.2,name=$device"
```

Comment: Any link to help find latest OS version that the Github actions supports? Thanks

Comment: @HongboMiao you can check the available versions here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners

Comment: You can also find details about installed software in the runners repo directly:
https://github.com/actions/runner-images?tab=readme-ov-file#available-images

for example, macos 13:
https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/macos/macos-13-Readme.md